# Getting Exception for canvas in firefox

Tags: jquery, exception, canvas, html5-canvas

I am using canvas to display some reports in **Iframe**, it works fine in chrome but shows the following exception in firefox

Exception in firefox only:

```
[Exception... "Failure"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:21292/IndexPage/VehiclebasedDashboard.aspx?vehicleNo=ALL :: getDashborddetails/< :: line 346"  data: no]
```

JSFiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/ue9j9rfp/

Below is my code:

```
  var i = 0, j = 0,Empid = data[0].Empid;     
  var strokecolor = ["#7f8c8d", '#2ecc71', '#F38231', '#e74c3c', '#f1c40f'];
  var fillcolor = ["#7f8c8d", '#2ecc71', '#F38231', '#e74c3c', '#f1c40f'];
  $.each(data[0], function (key, value) {  
     $('#dv_veh_mn_usr').append('<canvas id="cnv_veh_usr_' + i + '"  width="100" height="100" class="cls_veh_cnvs ' + Empid + '_' + key + '">Browser not support, Please upgrade your browser</canvas>');
     var c = document.getElementById("cnv_veh_usr_" + i++);
     var ctx = c.getContext("2d");                        
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.arc(50, 50, 45, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
     ctx.lineWidth = 4;
     ctx.strokeStyle = strokecolor[j];
     ctx.fillStyle = fillcolor[j];
     **ctx.font = "30px Arial";**
     ctx.textAlign = "center"; 
     ctx.fillText(value, c.width / 2.1, c.height / 1.7);
     ctx.font = "10px Arial"; ctx.textAlign = "center";
     ctx.fillText(key.replace('V_', ''), c.width / 2.1, c.height / 1.7);
     ctx.stroke();
     (j < 4) ? j++ : j = 0;
  });
```

At **ctx.font** the error occurs and it jumps to outer catch block

I searched in net but could not get proper solution. When i run this in individual page it works fine but when i run it in an iframe the above error occurs

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ue9j9rfp/ it works fine here

Comment: Ditto, works fine in win8.1 FF35.0.1

Comment: @markE need help for windows 7 firefox 36

Comment: @markE even in win 7 firefox 36 works fine in jsfiddle but when i run in my application , got the above exception

Comment: @markE  i forgot to tell below  At ctx.font the error occurs and it jumps to outer catch block

I searched in net but could not get proper solution. When i run this in individual page it works fine but when i run it in an iframe the above error occurs

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara At ctx.font the error occurs and it jumps to outer catch block

I searched in net but could not get proper solution. When i run this in individual page it works fine but when i run it in an iframe the above error occurs